# How to setup Hasura CLI?

Tags: react-native, graphql, hasura, hasura-cli

I installed Hasura CLI and I want to send data on my Hasura cloud project. I tried different ways to launch Hasura console but I don't find the good way to launch it. Every time I have the same error and I don't know how to solve it.

You can see my Hasura CLI config file in my project and the error.

> ERRO connecting to graphql-engine server failed
> INFO possible reasons:
> INFO 1) Provided root endpoint of graphql-engine server is wrong. Verify endpoint key in config.yaml or/and value of --endpoint flag
> INFO 2) Endpoint should NOT be your GraphQL API, ie endpoint is NOT https://hasura-cloud-app.io/v1/graphql it should be: https://hasura-cloud-app.io
> INFO 3) Server might be unhealthy and is not running/accepting API requests
> INFO 4) Admin secret is not correct/set
> INFO
> FATA[0002] making http request failed: Get "http://localhost:8080/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused

[image: HasuraCLI error]

[image: ConfigFile Hasura]

Comment: Are you sure the Hasura server is running at localhost:8080? Since you mentioned you wanted to use Hasura Cloud project, can you pass the project URL as the endpoint. 

For example: `hasura console --endpoint https://myapp.hasura.app --admin-secret xxxx` and try it out.

Comment: yes i try this solution from my terminal and in the file config.yaml but still the same error. When I launch the project, I have this error : ```x-hasura-admin-secret/x-hasura-access-key required, but not found``` But my key is in my file

Answer (score 0):

resolved :

When we use apollo client, we need to set the header in the client like this :

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://yourapp.hasura.app/v1/graphql",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-hasura-admin-secret":
      "",
  },
});
```

this fix my problem

Comment: That does not answer the question at all. You figured out how to use apollo but you did not figure out how to start the console.

Answer (score 0):

I Had two versions of hasura-cli, one installed with curl and one installed with npm.

I resolve the problem by removing all the version and installing the hasura-cli with npm and restarting the system

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).